# notepad.exe is not opening in tomcat but works in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, tomcat

My requirement is to open the notepad using processbuilder.
If we run the

```
C:\>notepad.exe
```

In command line or eclipse (through java using processbuilder )the process is created like below.

```
Name                        PID         status           UserName 
notepad.exe                  8380      Running         Selva
```

The process is created in task manager and also notepad is opening and we can able to execute the command again and again.

But If we run the command from Tomcat using java process builder(Tomcat started through services.msc) the process is created like below.

```
 Name                        PID         status           UserName 
    notepad.exe                 8380       Running         SYSTEM
```

The process is created in task manager.But notepad is not opening in the system and also we can't able to run the command again.Because it's showing,
"The process cannot be accessible,because it's being used by another process"

Why the process is created with the name "SYSTEM" instead of "Selva" in tomcat and why the notepad is not opening.

How to fix this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Probably [RunAs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx).

Comment: it asking prompt @wOxxOm

Comment: I think the documentation I've linked describes how to handle it. Also you can use google to find examples of using `RunAs` with credentials, it will only take a few seconds/minutes.

Comment: Have the Tomcat service log in as a user, and be sure to check the "interact with desktop" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Services run in the background - regardless whether a user is logged on or not. Thus they usually have no access to the GUI. Windows redirects their GUI output to a 'hidden' desktop.

This problem is per Windows design and not related to Java. See also [Swing JDialog is showing fine when I run it from eclipse but not working from windows service(services.msc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191958/swing-jdialog-is-showing-fine-when-i-run-it-from-eclipse-but-not-working-from-wi/65782791#65782791)