# Swing JDialog is showing fine when I run it from eclipse but not working from windows service(services.msc)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, batch-file, windows-services

I have a java application which runs in a certain interval of time and show a popup(made with java swing). When I run the application from eclipse it works fine. After I created a jar and run it using java -jar command, It is also working fine. But when I run the jar file from windows service(services.msc) Popup window is not appeared, except popup all are working properly such as logging data fetching etc.
I did not find any solution for that I have applied all the solution in stack overflow but the problem persist.

I have pasted all the information.

Thanks In advance

Java code (this method will be called in interval)

```
public static void showUserMsg(final int MsgId, String msgText) {
        logger.info("Entry in showUserMsg to show notification");
        logger.info("Message: " + msgText);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        final int screenWidth = (int) dim.getWidth();
        final int screenHeight = (int) dim.getHeight();
        try {
//          JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(new JFrame());
            dialog.setTitle("You have message");
            dialog.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
//          dialog.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,18)); 
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.setSize(600, 450);
            dialog.setLocation(screenWidth / 2 - 250 + 171, screenHeight / 2 - 250);
            dialog.setResizable(true);
            dialog.setModal(false);
            dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            dialog.requestFocus();
            final Image img = ImageIO.read(EcsApplication.class.getResource("icons/notify.png"));
            dialog.setIconImage(img);

            logger.info("Dialog location: " + dialog.getLocation());

            Container pane = dialog.getContentPane();
            JTextPane contentLabel = new JTextPane();
            contentLabel.setText("\n\n\n\n\n" + msgText);
            contentLabel.setEditable(false);
            contentLabel.setVisible(true);
            contentLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 18));
            contentLabel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
            contentLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Yes, I have read the message");

            okButton.setBounds(120, 330, 400, 50);
            okButton.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 18));
            okButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(68, 155, 221), 1));
            okButton.setBackground(new Color(144, 186, 227));
            okButton.setFocusable(true);
            okButton.setVisible(true);

            StyledDocument doc = contentLabel.getStyledDocument();
            SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);

            pane.add(okButton);
            pane.add(contentLabel);

            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    logger.info("windowClosing event");
                    try {
                        statusByMsgId(MsgId);
                        JDialog warning = new JDialog();
                        warning.setTitle("Information");
                        warning.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                        warning.setVisible(true);
                        warning.setSize(300, 150);
                        warning.setLocation(screenWidth / 2 - 150, screenHeight / 2 - 150);
                        warning.setResizable(false);
                        warning.setModal(true);
                        warning.requestFocus();
                        warning.setIconImage(img);

                        Container pane = warning.getContentPane();
                        pane.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
                        JTextPane warningMsg = new JTextPane();
                        warningMsg.setText("You have read the message");
                        warningMsg.setEditable(false);
                        warningMsg.setVisible(true);
                        warningMsg.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);

                        warningMsg.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 14));

                        StyledDocument doc1 = warningMsg.getStyledDocument();
                        SimpleAttributeSet center1 = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center1, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        doc1.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc1.getLength(), center1, false);

                        pane.add(warningMsg);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                }
            });

            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    logger.info("OK button clicked.");
                    try {
                        statusByMsgId(MsgId);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
//                      InfoLogger.printInfo(EcsService.class, "showUserMsg", "Dialog box not loaded.");
//                      InfoLogger.printExceptionLog("EcsService", "showUserMsg", ex);

                        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

                    }

                    dialog.setVisible(false);

                }

            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        logger.info("Exit in showUserMsg");
    }
```

Folder structure to create service:

[image: Main folser]

[image: inside common folder]

Inside the classes folder java class file is present :

```
public class EcsClientService
{
    Process proc;
    private static EcsClientService serviceInstance;
    private boolean stopped;
    
    public EcsClientService() {
        this.stopped = false;
    }
    
    public static void windowsService(final String[] array) {
        String anObject = "start";
        if (array.length > 0) {
            anObject = array[0];
        }
        if ("start".equals(anObject)) {
            EcsClientService.serviceInstance.start();
        }
        else {
            EcsClientService.serviceInstance.stop();
        }
    }
    
    public void start() {
        this.stopped = false;
        try {
            System.out.println("currentDirectory>>> " + new File(EcsClientService.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().replace("%20", " "));
            this.proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start ECSClientService.bat");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!this.stopped) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    this.wait(60000L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex2) {}
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        this.stopped = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();
        }
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic Path win32_process Where \"CommandLine Like '%ECSClientService.bat%' OR CommandLine Like '%-jar ECSClientService.jar%'\" Call Terminate");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
    
    static {
        EcsClientService.serviceInstance = new EcsClientService();
    }
}
```

InstallService.bat

```
for /f %%i in ("%20") do set curpath=%%~dpi

common\ecsClient.exe //DS//ECSClientService

common\ecsClient.exe //IS//ECSClientService --Install=%curpath%\common\ecsClient.exe --Description="Employee Communication Service" --Jvm=auto --Classpath=%curpath%\common\classes --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=EcsClientService --StartMethod=windowsService --StartParams=start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=EcsClientService --StopMethod=windowsService --StopParams=stop --StopMode=jvm --Startup=auto --LogPath=common\logs --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto


pause
```

StartService.bat

```
common\ecsClient.exe //ES//ECSClientService
```

StopService.bat

```
common\ecsClient.exe //SS//ECSClientService
```

UninstallService.bat

```
common\ecsClient.exe //DS//ECSClientService
```

ECSClientService.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET CampaignArg=%1
for /f %%i in ("%0") do set curpath=%%~dpi
cd /d %curpath%
java -jar ECSClientService.jar %CampaignArg%
pause
```

Comment: If you are running it as a Windows service, then it may be running in [headless mode](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html) which means you don't have access to the computer screen and therefore cannot display a dialog window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is not in Java. AFAIK services run in the background - regardless whether a user is logged on or not. Thus they usually have no access to the GUI.

If your application shall run in the background but in user context, maybe you want to move your application to the autostart program folder so Windows will start it when a user logs on.